# PowerShell ADSI query leads to 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))"

Tags: .net, powershell, exception

The query for some AD users TS Home Directory below, leads to an `DotNetException`. What is wrong with my code? And what is this exception trying to tell me?

```
$userObject = Get-ADUser someUser -Properties *
$userObject.userParameters

$adsiObject = [adsi]"LDAP://$($userObject.DistinguishedName)"
$adsiObject.PSBase.InvokeGet("TerminalServicesHomeDirectory");
```

**Output:**

```
                                                PCtxCfgPresent㔵攱戰ぢCtxCfgFlags1〰て〲〹CtxCallback〰〰〰〰CtxShadow㌰〰〰〰(CtxMaxConnectionTime〰〰〰〰.CtxMaxDisconnectionTime〰〰〰〰CtxMaxIdleTime〰〰〰〰"CtxKeyboardLayout〰〰〰〰*CtxMinEncryptionLevel
㄰ CtxWorkDirectory〰 CtxNWLogonServer〰CtxWFHomeDir〰"CtxWFHomeDirDrive〰 CtxWFProfilePath〰"CtxInitialProgram〰"CtxCallbackNumber〰

Exception calling "InvokeGet" with "1" argument(s): "Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))"
At D:\SourceCode\PowerShell\Get-ADTSProperties.ps1:125 char:1
+ $adsiObject.PSBase.InvokeGet("TerminalServicesHomeDirectory");
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

So the attribute `userParameters` is there and holds data.

Comment: Check with ADSIEdit if the AD schema really has such an attribute, and if yes, check if the user doesn't have a null in there. Also, since your `userParameters` indicate you have Citrix installed in your AD, maybe thr proper attribute name contains "Ctx" inside.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out by myself. The library `tsuserex.dll` was not registered which provides exports to read the `userParameters` BLOB.

[How to read msTSProfilePath, msTSHomeDrive and msTSHomeDirectory properties from AD (VB.NET)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2010/10/13/how-to-read-mstsprofilepath-mstshomedrive-and-mstshomedirectory-properties-from-ad-vb-net.aspx)